# Obtain first name, last name with unknown number of space

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm new in VB.NET programming but I have to do a research bar in my program.  Actually, the search bar is looking for first name or for last name (If first name or last name have space it's working) but if I want to search for both, how can I build my sql query? I don't know if the user will put first name first or last name first. What I've tried is to split the names if there is a space but if the person have a name like 'Robert Downey Junior', how can I know which part of the space will be the first name or the last name?

So,

- how can I build my sql query for this task?
- how can I know which part of the space will be the first name or the last name?

**Actual regex**

```
' value of query = "% + search bar + %" for sql LIKE parameter    
Regex.IsMatch(query, "^'%(\w+ \w+)+%'$")
```

**How I detect the first and last names**

```
Dim name As String = query.ToString.Substring(2, query.Length - 4)
Dim nameParts As String() = name.Split(" ")
'So nameParts(0) = "robert", nameParts(1) = "downey" and namePart(2) = "junior"
```

**Actual sql selector**

```
SELECT id, firstName, lastName 
FROM beneficiaire 
WHERE LOWER(lastName) LIKE '%robert downey junior%' 
   OR LOWER(firstName) LIKE '%robert downey junior%'
```

Comment: There is no way to perform this differentiation (not even a person can tell). You have to set input rules. For example: comma means "Family Name", "Name"; no comma means "Name" "Family Name". If you have more than two elements, you would have to set other rules for the middle name, etc. Without constraints, your problem is unsolvable. In any case, the inputs should be introduced somewhere and the given inputboxes should be adequately labelled.

Comment: That was exactly my second thought. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: And it gets even trickier from there. For example, what's Robert Downey Jr.'s last name? Hint: it doesn't contain the letters J or R. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE SEARCH( @SearchName VARCHAR(50)) AS

 DECLARE @name VARCHAR(52)
 SET '%' + @SearchName + '%'

 SELECT id, 
        firstName, 
        lastName 
 FROM   beneficiaire 
 WHERE  (
             LOWER(lastName) + ' ' + LOWER(firstName) LIKE @name
        )    OR
        (
             LOWER(firstName) + ' ' + LOWER(lastName) LIKE @name
        )
```